# Prevent keyboard event from bubbling (propagating to parents) in Flutter

Tags: flutter, events, keyboard, event-propagation

I am using RawKeyboardListener to detect the escape key to close (pop) windows, but I can't **use** the event and prevent it from bubbling (propagating) to parent windows, so all parent windows will receive escape and will close!

I tried using **Focus** element and it's **onKey** too, but not difference.

```
return Scaffold(
  body: RawKeyboardListener(
    focusNode: FocusNode(),
    onKey: (RawKeyEvent event) {
      if (event.logicalKey == LogicalKeyboardKey.escape) {
      Navigator.pop(context);
    }},
    autofocus: true,
    child: Container(
      child: Text("blah blah")
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

Comment: *"I am using RawKeyboardListener to detect the escape key"* - your code does not detect the escape key in any way: you call `pop()` method unconditionally

Comment: just typo in the question, updated it, thanks.

Comment: the events dont bubble to parent window (page): now your `onKey` is called twice (for key down and up)

Comment: Yes, it's bubbled, I added logs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can attach the key listener to focus Node this listener will return a KeyEventResult enum that determines that the key event is handled or not

```
   var focus = FocusNode(onKey: (FocusNode node, RawKeyEvent event) {
      if (event.logicalKey == LogicalKeyboardKey.escape)
      {
        return KeyEventResult.handled;
      }
      return KeyEventResult.ignored;
    });
```

Also here is the KeyEventResult description :

```
/// An enum that describes how to handle a key event handled by a
/// [FocusOnKeyCallback].
enum KeyEventResult {
  /// The key event has been handled, and the event should not be propagated to
  /// other key event handlers.
  handled,
  /// The key event has not been handled, and the event should continue to be
  /// propagated to other key event handlers, even non-Flutter ones.
  ignored,
  /// The key event has not been handled, but the key event should not be
  /// propagated to other key event handlers.
  ///
  /// It will be returned to the platform embedding to be propagated to text
  /// fields and non-Flutter key event handlers on the platform.
  skipRemainingHandlers,
}
```